# SSL , Number of insecure items: 1

Tags: html, css, security, ssl

After my website went live i did a SSL test on it to see if all my pages, links etc.. is secure.

I found that it all good and secured but i got one image that throws an error.

**Example:**

> Total number of items: 119
>
> Number of insecure items: 1
>
> Insecure URL:
> http://www.example.org/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/foot-logo.png

Now i went in the root and because i dont need that image, i deleted it from the directory, now for some reason even after doing a hard refresh i still end up getting this error.

I checked my css file for any hard coded links to this image but did not find any..Any help or tips please?

Comment: FYI: Even if you delete the file, the URL request for it is still somewhere. It doesn't matter at all whether something exists behind that URL.

Comment: Maybe there is a reference in your html?

Comment: oeps, oky so i found the a tag around the tag which displays the image was linked using http// , but now even after i update the link it still shows the error?

Comment: Do you have a link?

Comment: i realised my theme calls my url as php inside a tag - `<a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>">`

Comment: `<a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' , 'https') ); ?>">`  - would adding https be the solution?

Comment: You want to use SSL -  so yes https is the solution.